# Write Exception to a file

Tags: c#, list, foreach, sqlexception

I am trying to call 2 stored procs,for each data row in a data table.
When an exception occurred in these Sp's I m trying to catch the exception and send to a file.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Error.txt",false);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        UpdateEvent(LN);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        //continue; 
    }

    try
    {
        insertevent(LN, note);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    foreach (string line in error)
    {
        file.WriteLine(line);      
    }   
}
```

Can I remove the line from the list..which is written to file..so that it wont print again to file.
I tried error.remove(line)...but it didn't work..

also i get the error to file as ...below..

can i format it to a simple two lines by any chance??

Comment: Side note, take a look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), it's much easier to configure error logging into a file.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, to add a line in the file between exceptions do this:

```
 foreach (string line in error)
 {
    file.WriteLine(line);
    file.WriteLine();  //write blank line
 }
```

Also, write your file outside your loop, after the loop is finished.  Then you won't have duplicate lines in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You must exit your loop from first loop.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Error.txt",false);
List<string> error = new List<string>();
          foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
          {
                        try
                        {
                            UpdateEvent(LN);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            error.Add(String.Format("Exception for Loan Number {0} with a Error {1}", row["LN"].ToString(), e.ToString()));
                            //continue; 
                         }
                        try
                        {
                            insertevent(LN, note);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            error.Add(String.Format("Exception for Loan Number {0} with a Error {1}", row["LN"].ToString(), e.ToString()));
                            //continue; 
                         }
            }

            foreach (string line in error)
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Is there any way I can format the error?Even though I m formatting...its giving a 10 line error..into a file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Enterprise library to do it much more easily and it is more customizable.

Comment: You can choose what to write (programmatically), but you can configure for what types of exceptions, write to which files, etc. with visual tool. You can create exception policies and apply them to your methods in AOP fashion as well if you want. Helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664360(v=pandp.50).aspx, there are more samples online if you look for it.

Comment: ok got it..when I give e.message.tostring() i get only the message of an error..instead of all trace..thanks anyways..